# Compare 2 text file contents in c# and remove same content

Tags: c#

I have 2 text file in C# say: File  A & File  B. I want to compare both file contents and if there is any content found in File  A which is present in File  B then i want to remove that content in File  B .

So if is there any method in c# which can do this for me then please let me know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare the lines you could use this query:

```
var newLines = File.ReadLines(f2Path).Except(File.ReadLines(f1Path)).ToList();
File.WriteAllLines(f2Path, newLines);
```

---

**Edit**: according to your comment(s)

> i want to exclude all lines from file2 where the id exists in file1

You could use this [left-outer-join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx) with LINQ:

```
var idInF2 = from f2Line in File.ReadLines(f2Path)
             join f1Line in File.ReadLines(f1Path)
             on f2Line.Split(',')[0].Trim() equals f1Line.Split(',')[0].Trim() into gj
             from lineOne in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where lineOne == null
             select f2Line;
File.WriteAllLines(f2Path, idInF2.ToList());
```

or you could use this more readable but less efficient approach using `Contains`:

```
var f1IDs = File.ReadLines(f1Path).Select(l => l.Split(',')[0].Trim());
var newLines = File.ReadLines(f2Path)
            .Select(l => new { Line = l, ID = l.Split(',')[0].Trim() })
            .Where(x => !f1IDs.Contains(x.ID))
            .Select(x => x.Line).ToList();
File.WriteAllLines(f2Path, newLines);
```

Comment: tnx for your response. but my data for example is: 123,absdefgh....(that it maybe as long as few line, not 1 line) each line have a id that is a ineger then seperate with , and a long characters is the value of this id, and the next data begin in another line

Comment: @mahsamahdavi: So you want to exclude all lines from file2 where the id exists in file1 or where the id and the string are the same?

Comment: i want to exclude all lines from file2 where the id exists in file1

Comment: @mahsamahdavi: i have edited my answer to provide two approaches.

Comment: @mahsamahdavi: you have unaccepted my answer after i've provided the other ways. Was something wrong?

Comment: tnx so much. thats correct.